# Bluemix - deploying code/app from Devops issue

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I am able to deploy node.js express app to Bluemix from CF command line successfully.

But when imported the code to Devops, made some changes, and tried to deploy the app is not starting. Error log says:

```
2016-02-17T10:26:18.081-0500
[API/2]
out
Updated app with guid 69a581c0-604f-4b86-804b-4acce924b00d ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
2016-02-17T10:26:18.201-0500
[STG/57]
out
-----> Downloaded app package (28K)
2016-02-17T10:26:18.412-0500
[STG/57]
out
-----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (452K)
2016-02-17T10:26:20.093-0500
[STG/0]
out
Staging failed: An application could not be detected by any available buildpack
2016-02-17T10:26:20.096-0500
[STG/0]
err
2016-02-17T10:26:20.330-0500
[API/2]
err
encountered error: An app was not successfully detected by any available buildpack
```

Any suggestions, not sure what I am missing.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a manifst.yml file in the root directory of your app?

Comment: Yes I do have it in the root directory

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the application directory contains the same files of when pushing from local. When you don’t specify the buildpack to use explicitly, Bluemix will then go through a “detect” process to try to find the right buildpack for your application by examining your application package and, for example if there is no package.json it is impossible to auto detect that the Node.js buildpack should be used and that error occurs.

Comment: I have the same files , which used for local push